# Cannot install package as it doesnt have package.json

Tags: node.js, npm

So when doing an npm run build I get the following error

```
Cannot find module: '@styles/react/libs/toastify/toastify.scss'. Make sure this package is installed.
[2021-05-27T08:03:15.123590112Z] 
[2021-05-27T08:03:15.123595462Z] You can install this package by running: npm install @styles/react/libs/toastify/toastify.scss.
```

However if I run the command it is telling me to `npm install @styles/react/libs/toastify/toastify.scss` it is telling me that

`Could not install from "@styles\react\libs\toastify\toastify.scss" as it does not contain a package.json file.`

I have tried deleting my node modules and doing a complete `npm install` again but that hasn't fixed it

Package.json

https://pastebin.com/qEUs8esc

Console

https://pastebin.com/znUKVdmt

Index.js

```
// ** React Imports
import { Suspense, lazy } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

// ** Redux Imports
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { store } from './redux/storeConfig/store'

// ** Toast & ThemeColors Context
import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify'
import { ThemeContext } from './utility/context/ThemeColors'

// ** Spinner (Splash Screen)
import Spinner from './@core/components/spinner/Fallback-spinner'

// ** Ripple Button
import './@core/components/ripple-button'

// ** PrismJS
import 'prismjs'
import 'prismjs/themes/prism-tomorrow.css'
import 'prismjs/components/prism-jsx.min'

// ** React Perfect Scrollbar
import 'react-perfect-scrollbar/dist/css/styles.css'

// ** React Toastify
import '@styles/react/libs/toastify/toastify.scss'

// ** Core styles
import './@core/assets/fonts/feather/iconfont.css'
import './@core/scss/core.scss'
import './assets/scss/style.scss'

// ** Service Worker
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker'

// ** Lazy load app
const LazyApp = lazy(() => import('./App'))

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Suspense fallback={<Spinner />}>
      <ThemeContext>
        <LazyApp />
        <ToastContainer newestOnTop />
      </ThemeContext>
    </Suspense>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
serviceWorker.unregister()
```

Comment: It says "cannot find _module_" and not "cannot find _package_", the "you can install this package blah blah" is misleading because the error comes from trying to read a certain file inside a package, not the main file of a package. This should probably be reported as a bug because the suggestion in the error doesn't make sense.

Comment: @CherryDT Ah I see, is a module a part of a package?

Comment: It can be, but it can also be part of your code. Anyway, to understand better what your actual problem is we'd need to know about the circumstances, can you show your package.json and maybe some more output of the build command before the error (if there is any)?

Comment: Sure, I have added them not via pastebin links for bette readability

Comment: Can you try installing https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toastify

Comment: @AyusMohanty I have just tried that and I get the same error as in the second paste bin

Comment: Are you importing this anywhere? @styles\react\libs\toastify\toastify.scss

Comment: @AyusMohanty Yes, in my index.js

Comment: Could you share that code. How you are doing there.

Comment: Yes I'll put the index.js in the question

Comment: Can you do this? `import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';` Instead of that import

Comment: If you need the scss you need to do `import 'react-toastify/scss/main.scss`

Comment: That doesn't fix it unfortunately